# Swift: Convert Integer x second to Date, x second ago

Tags: swift, date

I have an Integer for example `1572` (it's second), I want to know what the Date() `1572 seconds ago`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780053-init)

> Creates a date value initialized relative to the current date and time by a given number of seconds.

In your case:

```
let secondsAgo = 1572
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -TimeInterval(secondsAgo))
```

The method takes an `TimeInterval` (aka `Double`) argument, that's
why the integer needs to be converted.